# Can I use 'does' at the end of a question?

Tags: word-usage, questions, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement

So I was wondering if the correct phrase for asking a question is "what does it does/do?" Then it struck me that it feels odd to say "what does it does". Then I did some Googling and apparently the correct phrase is "what does it do?"

But my question is why does it uses 'do' at the end of the question? I mean, the subject in question is an 'it', so shouldn't it use 'does' instead of 'do'? Can't we use 'does' to end a question? or am I missing something?

Comment: After do/does/did follows an infinitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make questions in English, we invert word order, and this is easily when we are already using a verb that inverts easily, most likely a modal verb, *to be*, or *to have*.

> He **will** visit... -> When **will** he visit?
>
> He **is** angry because... -> Why **is** he angry?

But most verbs don't readily invert, and as such we use the auxiliary form of *to do* to make questions (or negations).

> He **runs** because... -> Why **does** he **run**?
>
> It **does**... -> What **does** it **do**?

The only verb(s) that get conjugated within a clause are the first, or the ones that tie directly to the subject and not another verb.

> He **does** not want to eat it.
>
> *Not:*  He **does** not **wants** to **eats** it.*
>
> He **is** eating and **will** go to sleep soon.
>
> *Not:* He **is** eating and **will** **goes** to sleep soon.*

This is the same case for questions. The auxiliary verb "to do" is tied to the subject in typical questions and as such is the conjugated verb, the verb that would normally be tied to the subject is tied then to "to do".

> **Does** he want to go the store with me? (As a statement: "He **does** want to go to the store with me.)
>
> *Not:* **Does** he **wants** to go to the store with me?* (As a statement: "He **does** **wants** to go to the store with me.*)
>
> But my question is why **does** it uses 'do' at the end of the question?
>
> *Not:* But my question is why **does** it **uses** 'do' at the end of the question?*

And, as such:

> What **does** it do?
>
> *Not:* What **does** it **does**?

Answer (score 0):

How you frame the **question** decides if *do/does/done* ends the sentence. Notice how all of the following questions are the same:

> Can you tell me what *it* does?
>
> Do you know what *it* does?
>
> What does *it* do?
>
> When/Where/Why/How is *it* done?

On a side note: *What does it do* is commonly a rhetorical question used in comfortable, conversational settings.

On a cheeky note: Can questions end in do? That one does. Do questions end in does? They certainly do.